# Can I restrict a ViewFlipper from flipping until an AsyncTask has been performed?

Tags: java, android

My application has a `ViewFlipper` with `3 ViewGroups` in it. Each `ViewGroup interaction` is dependent on data from a database. I'm using an AsyncTask to read from a database and return a Cursor when it's done. Before the AsyncTask is executed, I just want to display a single View in the `ViewFlipper` saying "Loading data, please wait.", is this possible somehow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Show the progress dialog in your `onPreExecute()` and dismiss it in the `onPostExecute()`. Something like this,

```
private class MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Integer, Integer, Integer[]> {
    private ProgressDialog myWait = null;

    // This is on the UI thread itself
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        myWait  = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
        myWait.setMessage("Loading data, please wait");
        myWait.setCancelable(false);
        myWait.show();
    }

    // Separate worker thread is used here 
    protected Integer[] doInBackground(Integer...params) {
        //do the database loading
        return <your result - goes to onPostExecute>;
    }

    // This is on the UI thread itself
    protected void onPostExecute(Integer[] resultCell) {
        if (myWait  != null) {
            myWait.dismiss();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How about If I move all my ViewFlipper ViewGroups into a different layout xml and then inflate them into the ViewFlipper onPostExecute, or is that a bad idea?

Comment: Once the progress dialog is dismissed, you would be taken back to views that were displayed before. Not quite getting why you would want to inflate them again if they are showing up alright (also inflating is an expensive operation)?

Answer (score 1):

yes you can make use of progressDialog. Do it like this,

```
progressDiaolg=ProgressDialog.show(Activity.this,"","Loading Images...");
 final Thread t=    new Thread(new Runnable() {
                            public void run() {
                                Log.i("Inside Thread", "Downloading Images...");

                                downloadImages();

                              handler.sendEmptyMessage(0);

                            }

                        });
    t.start();
    handler = new Handler() {
        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {

            try {

                progressDiaolg.dismiss();
            } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

    };
```

I don't have idea with Asynctask. So try modifying this snippet accordingly.

Comment: Does the progressDialog restrict all interaction with the UI until the Handler dismisses it?

Comment: If you want to be sure a thread exits with the rest of your application, no matter what, a good technique is to call `Thread.setDaemon(true)` after creation and before you start the thread. However. source.rar provided a better answer to your question since he specifically used an `AsyncTask`, as you specified.

Comment: Yes. ProgressDialog can be used to stop the interactions until the task is completed, else you can override setCancelable() of ProgressDialog to achieve what you want.